# Jquery to multiply value in text box with button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to be able to get what was in the input box and multiply or divide.

what i have is taking the value from the span and that is not what i want

even if i hard code 500 in there it is not working.  i know im missing something simple but cant find it 
here is what i have on jfiddle  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dp170xr3/)

```
<?php
$wager="500";
?>

Wager: $<span id="wager"><?php echo $wager; ?></span>
<br> Total
<input type="text" id="count" value="<?php echo $wager; ?>">
<input type="button" data-quantity=".5" value="/&#x00A;2">
<input type="button" data-quantity="2" class="mnozstvi_sleva" value="x&#x00A;2">
<br>
```

then this javascript

```
$('input:button').click(function() {
$('#count').val($(this).data('quantity') * $('#wager').text());
});
```

EDIT: it will work if i put value the same as the span...  i want to be able to type anything in the boz and multiply/divide it.

second EDIT this is what i have in the page now  and it is not working

```
 <html>
 <head>

 </head>
 <body>
 <input type="number" id="count" style="height:25px; width:100px" name="wager" value="" min="00.25" max="25" step="00.25" numberFormat="1.00">
 <input type="button" data-quantity=".5" value="/&#x00A;2">
 <input type="button" data-quantity="2" class="mnozstvi_sleva" value="x&#x00A;2">
<br>

<script>
    $('input:button').click(function(){
    $('#count').val($(this).data('quantity') * $('#count').val());
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Then why are you multiplying by `$'#wager').text()`? If you want the input's value, use `$('#count').val()`.

Comment: i have edited it, do u see the mistake now?

Comment: The script element needs to be after the button element (just before closing `</body>` tag), or you could wrap the code in a document ready handler.

Comment: edited and still nothing, i do need to keep code close to as is  and not add a handler cause its being added to already working form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this works.  Make sure you're binding the event after the element is available in the page.  This is done by executing the JavaScript after the DOM is ready:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('input:button').click(function() {
    var $count = $('#count');
    $count.val( $(this).data('quantity') * $count.val() );
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="count" style="height:25px; width:100px" name="wager" value="" min="00.25" max="25" step="00.25" numberFormat="1.00">
<input type="button" data-quantity=".5" value="/&#x00A;2">
<input type="button" data-quantity="2" class="mnozstvi_sleva" value="x&#x00A;2">
```

Answer (score 1):

get the input value by using the `id` of the input.

```
$('input:button').click(function(){
    $('#count').val($(this).data('quantity') * $('#count').val());
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dp170xr3/1/)

Comment: it works on jfiddle but not my site.   how should i put it in my site?  i put it in <head>